# Oracle SQL - If X < 0 Then 0

Tags: sql, oracle

Sometimes there is a need for returning `0` if the result you obtain is `< 0`.  I would like a simplified, readable, no-redundancy way of doing that.  Something to replace and greatly simplify something like:

```
Select
    Case 
        When Amount_Required - Amount_In_Stock < 0 Then 0
        Else Amount_Required - Amount_In_Stock
        End as Amount_Needed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some playing, I think this is a valid method:

```
Select
    Greatest(0, Required - In_Stock) as Needed
```

Seems fairly readable, especially if it becomes a standard practice.  No redundancy of the expression `Amount_Needed - Amount_In_Stock`.  About as short as I think it could possibly be.

Additionally, if you wish to have a # cap, to replace something like:

```
Case
    When X+Y > 9999 Then 9999
    Else X+Y
    End as Z
```

you can use a similar method.

```
Select 
    Least(9999, Attack - Defense) as Damage --Cap attack damage at 9999
```

This example doesn't make any sense for a query, but you get the idea.

Comment: cool, posted a question and answered it in less than a minute!

Comment: @tbone :) I mostly wanted to share it with folks as I haven't seen it elsewhere and was excited about it.  When creating a question there's an option to do a "Q&A" type post, where you ask and then answer the question.  I haven't checked my answer since I want to see if anyone has a better solution or can point out flaws in this one.

Comment: no problem, was just poking fun anyway.  I'm sure this will be useful to someone in future, thanks